# grep to read exact data from text file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I have file test1.txt file, i am trying to read variable which is enclosed in double quotes and starting with hyphen for eg: "**-color**". i trying to use this grep command **cat test1.txt | grep getParm | sed 's/getParm(/  /;s/&/  /;s/,/  /;s/"/  /g' |  awk  '{print  $3}'** , where i am not able to read exact data for all variables present in file. for some of variables which is enclosed in **if...else** condition i don't get exact data. Please help me to read the data required. i have posted required data in question.

```
cat test1.txt | grep getParm

 if(!param.getParm(buf, "-logFile"))
   parameters()->getParm(&color, "-color");
   if (param.getParm(&species, "-species"))
   if (param.getParm(&width, "-width"))
   if (param.getParm(&xferLength, "-length"))
   else if (param.getParm(&xferLength, "-LargeTransferLength"))
   if (param.getParm(&cmdLineIoParms->pattern, "-pattern"))
      param.getParm(&cmdLineParams->volume,"-volume");
```

```
    cat test1.txt | grep getParm | sed 's/getParm(/  /;s/&/  /;s/,/  /;s/\"/  /g' |  awk  '{print  $3}'

    -logFile
    -color
    species
    width
    xferLength
    (param.
    cmdLineIoParms->pattern
    -volume
```

expected ouput:-

```
-logFile
-color
-species
-width
-length
-LargeTransferLength
-pattern
-volume
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep, positiv lookbehind, a non-greedy `*` and positiv lookahead:

```
... | grep -oP '(?<=")-.*?(?=")'
```

Output:

```
-logFile
-color
-species
-width
-length
-LargeTransferLength
-pattern
-volume
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following once. We could do this in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk '/getParm/ && match($0,/"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Simple explanation would be, searching string `getParm` and using `match` function to match everything from `"` till first occurrence of `"`, then printing sub string of matched regex here, which is expected output shown by OP.

Answer (score 3):

To round out the selection, you can use `sed` as well, with extended Regex, you could do:

```
sed -E '/getParm/s/^[^"]+"([^"]+).*$/\1/' file
```

or with BRE, you would have:

```
sed '/getParm/s/^[^"]*"\([^"][^"]*\).*$/\1/' file
```

Essentially it locates each line containing `getParm` and then uses the normal substitute form to match everything up to the first `'"'` then captures the contents up to the next `'"'` and reinserts what was captured as the first numbered backreference `\1`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `file` you would have:

```
$ sed -E '/getParm/s/^[^"]+"([^"]+).*$/\1/' file
-logFile
-color
-species
-width
-length
-LargeTransferLength
-pattern
-volume
```